# script that runs during suspend

Tags: networking, suspend, 17.04

I'm trying to run a script that will execute a command before and after the system is suspended I created a script in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/

The script works great but ends up running after the lan is disconnected.
For my purposes I need my scrip to run sooner as my task is a web based call.

Any direction or guidance will be appreciated.

17.04

Julio

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I need exact same thing.